# ADF - Pipeline expression builder to constract a folderpath

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF to copy files from several folders in a container on a storage account.
My container name is `cont01` and the folder structure is as follow :

```
cont01:
    --projA
      --Sub01
       --Sub02
        --2022-10-01
          -file01_A.gz
          -file02_A.gz
          -file03_A.gz
          -file04_A.gz
        --2022-10-02
          -file01_B.gz
          -file02_B.gz
          -file03_B.gz
          -file04_B.gz
```

The aim is copying all the files starting with `file01` into a destination container.
To do so, I create a pipeline with `GetMetadata` activity and `filter` on Folders and then I want to use `ForEach` to iterate throuth the folders. To get the list of files inside each folder I need to use another `GetMetadata` activity inside the ForEach which then the `dataset` needs a `File Path` which has to be a dynamic path ! something like : `proj01/Sub01/Sub02/` `+` the outcome of `ForEach` like `item().name`

[image]

How can I dynamically point to my ForEach outcomes ?

Comment: You want all files list in your source container to your destination? and is the above container structure is original or only a sample?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula, it is just an example, and as I mentioned above, I need to copy the files start with `file01` to destination

Comment: Is the number of subdirectories in your source folder same? I mean the directory level same or different for each file?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula they are the same

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the above and got the below result.

As you said the levels of all files are same, you can copy the files that starts with `file01` with below approach.

These are my sample files in source container. Here for sample, I have used csv files.

[image]

First use **Get Meta data activity** to get all files list. Use a dataset parameter as wild card placeholder.

[image]

This will give you all files list inside the source container.

[image]

Then Use **filter activity** to filter the files starts with `file01`.

Items - `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

Condition - `@startswith(item().name,'file01')`

[image]

You will get the required files list.

[image]

Give this Values array to **Foreach activity** as `@activity('Filter1').output.Value`.

Inside Foreach use copy activity and give the `@item().name` in the wild card path of source as follows.

[image]

In sink Dataset, give the same `@item().name` by using a dataset parameter.

[image]

Execute this pipeline and you will get the files in the target container.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in my case the folder structure also contains `cont01/projB/Sub01/Sub02/...` as well as `projC` , `D` , `...` . So I'm just interested in `ProjA` and in your example that get meta data activity sould read milions of milions of files :/

Comment: yeah, If your folder structure and level is same for all files it will work for all folders like `projB`,`projC`....etc. It will list of all child files on that level.

Comment: in your second screenshot, under the setting tab for `Get Metadata` activity, I do not have the option dataset property !!! how did you get that ?!!

Comment: In the Dataset Go to parameters and create one parameter, In the dynamic content of file path of dataset give that parameter. then it will show that in the Get Meta Data.

Comment: Creating dataset parameter https://i.imgur.com/I7nNhic.png and give that in dynamic content of file path of dataset https://i.imgur.com/7Ch9w5U.png

Comment: Did you follow the above screenshots in the comments?

Comment: I did, this method in `get metadata` we will list all the files in the `source` container in your example, corect ? if it is correct then it will take for ever because I have 50 project (I'm interested in just one of them let say projA), and I have since 2019 for every 10 minute one file :)

Comment: If you want the files only from one `ProjA` then in the Get Meta data parameter give the value as `ProjA/*/*/*/` like this.

Comment: Give the same `ProjA/*/*/*` in copy activity wild card path and `@item().name`.

Comment: I have 1000 folder and each folder has about 900 files so I'm expecting the Get metadata returns 1000*900 files but it returns just 1166 file !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248863/discussion-between-user9112767-and-rakesh-govindula).